How to load a specific dll file into a C# project using relative path?
I'm development a MAUI project with Mac Xamarin . I wrote a dll to handle HID interface but I would like to know that how to load the dll file with relative path but instead of absolute path in order to avoid from dll not found when running tool from a different notebook .  I've already added the dll file into my project and create a folder "Lib" for the dll .
I've write a function to handle the path of dll file , but the result is that the dll file couldn't not be setting after loading a function .

Did this link about Dynamically load a DLL from a specific folder? answer your question?

You can check this link about how to load the dll to your project.

Here is how I do it in my applications:

Generate a DLL and place it in a folder at the root of your solution (I personally use a "Libs") folder.

Open the .csproj file for the project you want to add the DLL to

Add the following section in your .csproj file, assuming that your dll is named "my.library"
 <Project>
     <!-- Other tags omitted-->

     <ItemGroup>
         <Reference Include="my.library">
         <HintPath>..\Libs\my.library.dll</HintPath>
     </ItemGroup>

 </Project>



Notice the '..\' that makes the path relative. If your folder structure is more complex, you might want to adapt this to your specific project structure
My folder structure is as follows:
Solution
    |- Project1
        |- Project1.csproj
        |- ...
    |- Project2
        |- Project1.csproj
        |- ...
    |- Libs
        |- my.library.dll

Then you should be able to use your DLL in your project by writing 'using my.library' in your code, and it should work regardless of the environment as the path is relative.
